# Https with Amazon linux 2 , receiving server not found error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using elasticbeanstalk : PHP 8.1 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.5.6 .

I have followed the bellow guidlines to establish https connection :

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-php.html

```
packages:
  yum:
    mod24_ssl : []

files:
  /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
      Listen 443
      <VirtualHost *:443>
        <Proxy *>
          Order deny,allow
          Allow from all
        </Proxy>

        SSLEngine             on
        SSLCertificateFile    "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt"
        SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key"
        SSLCipherSuite        EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH
        SSLProtocol           All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
        SSLHonorCipherOrder   On
        SSLSessionTickets     Off
        
        Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload"
        Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY
        Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
        
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:80/ retry=0
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:80/
        ProxyPreserveHost on
        RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https" early
        
      </VirtualHost>
      
  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt:
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
     My crt ………..
      -----END CERTIFICATE-----
      
  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key:
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
      My private key ………..
      -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

But I received the bellow error while deploying a new version : Yum does not have mod24_ssl available for installation

To fix the problem I updated the bellow code to mod_ssl:

```
yum:
        mod_ssl : []
```

But then there was no error while deploying new version, but once I tried to access my website on https I received the bellow error on chrome :

**This site can’t be reached**

How to use https with amazon elasticbeanstalk running linux 2 on single instance ?

Note: I don't prefer to run the bellow command : `sudo yum install -y mod24_ssl`

since I don't want to connect ssh to each instance every time the elasticbeanstalk environment add new instance .

Thanks

Comment: "server not found" this implies DNS lookup failure.  That has little to do with anything you've included.

Comment: @erik258 but the error is gone once I use mod24_ssl .